# How to write Mock test cases for Webtarget and Response for a rest client?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, powermock

```
WebTarget resource = clientLocal.target(/test/url))
Response response = resource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .header("Content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .header("Authorization", "Basic"+" "+"234YML")
                    .post(Entity.entity("", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN), Response.class);
responseEntity = response.readEntity(Test.class);
```

When `Response` object is mocked, `builder` object for Authorization header is returning *null*,

```
Mockito.when(mockWebTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).thenReturn(mockBuilder);
Mockito.when(mockBuilder.header("Content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .thenReturn(mockBuilder);
Mockito.when(mockBuilder.header("Authorization",eq(anyString())))
        .thenReturn(mockBuilder);
Mockito.when(mockBuilder.post(Entity.entity(anyString(), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN), eq(Response.class)))
        .thenReturn(mockResponse);
```

How the second part of header should be mocked so that it does not return *null* value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eq(anyString())` is the problem in

```
Mockito.when(mockBuilder.header("Authorization",eq(anyString())))
    .thenReturn(mockBuilder);
```

It should be

```
Mockito.when(mockBuilder.header(eq("Authorization"), anyString()))
    .thenReturn(mockBuilder);
```

The argument matcher `eq` is used for literal matches.

Also if you are using argument matchers, **all arguments** have to be provided by matchers.

The first one worked because all the arguments were literal values.

That would also mean that

```
Mockito.when(mockBuilder.post(Entity.entity(anyString(), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN), eq(Response.class)))
    .thenReturn(mockResponse);
```

needs to change to

```
Mockito.when(mockBuilder.post(any(Entity.class), eq(Response.class)))
    .thenReturn(mockResponse);
```